# Calculate perpendicular distance from a vertical and horizontal line in

Tags: math, geometry

I have two lines one horizontal and one vertical, I have the equations of lines in the format:

[image]

and [image] as it is a horizontal line and [image] for the vertical line and I can calculate [image] because I know a point from which the lines passes by.

I want to calculate the perpendicular distance of a point in [image] space from each of these lines. I can't use the slop as it will give divide by 0 error. What is the other approach?

Comment: I don't get it. If the lines are horizontal and vertical, you just have that $d_y = |y-c|$ and $d_x = x$ (if the vertical line passes through 0).

Comment: ahh i get it , i can just subtract the y co-ordinate of the point and c for horizontal line and for vertical line i can subtract x co-ordinate of the point and c . Once i drew the situation it was quite clear.

Comment: Then the equation of that line is x = d, with d a constant. You thus have $d_x = |x-d|$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the horizontal line the equation is `y = c` and so the distance of any general point `(a,b)` from that line is simply `|b-c|`.

In the vertical line, `c` is meaningless as the line never crosses the y axis (unless it is the y axis). The equation of such a line is `x = d` (you need to calculate d) then the distance of a point `(a,b)` from this line is simply `|a-d|`

**EDIT:** By the way this question really has nothing at all to do with C++

Comment: That was to suggest that if somebody provides the code it should be c++ .

Answer (score 0):

Beyond the fact that this problem is already solved:

For future issues like that use the normalized form

```
c = a*x + b*y;
```